# On every simply connected domain, there exists a holomorphic function with no analytic continuation.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

I am working on a question that requires me to prove that *on every simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, there exists a holomorphic function that cannot be extended to a holomorphic function on a larger connected open set.*

I know an example of such a holomorphic function on the open unit disc: $$f:z\mapsto\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n!}.$$ I tried to combine this with the Riemann mapping theorem.

Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and one may assume that $\Omega$ is not the entire complex plane. By the Riemann mapping theorem, there exists a conformal equivalence $$\phi:\Omega\rightarrow D$$where $D$ is the open unit disc. Then my guess is that $f\circ\phi$ has no analytic continuation, but then I had to link the boundaries of $\Omega$ and of $D$ and I don't know what is going on between $\partial\Omega$ and $\partial D$.

Could anyone offer any idea? Many thanks!

Comment: If $\partial \Omega$ is a Jordan curve then [boundary maps to boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping)).

Comment: @A.G.homeomorphisms map boundaries to boundaries.

Comment: @Gary.That is not true. For example, the unit disc and the right half plane are conformally equivalent, but a circle is not homeomorphic to a straight line (by compactness).

Comment: Better example: A disk and a slit disk.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think this has much to do with simple connectivity. Let $U\subset \mathbb {C}$ be any open set with non-empty boundary. Claim: There exists $f\in H(U)$ such that

$$\sup_{D(a,r)\cap U} |f|=\infty$$

for every $a \in \partial U$ and $r>0.$ This $f$ cannot be be extended analytically to any larger open set containing a point in $\partial U.$

Proof: Let $\{a_1,a_2, \dots \}$ be a countable dense subset of $\partial U.$ The idea is to define

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{c_n}{z-a_n}$$

for appropriate positive constants $c_n.$

To do this, we choose pairwise disjoint countably infinite sets $E_1, E_2,\dots \subset U$ such that for each $n,$ the only limit point of $E_n$ in $\mathbb {C}$ is $a_n.$ (For each $n,$ $E_n$ is just a sequence of distinct points in $U$ whose limit is $a_n.$  You can choose the $E_n$'s inductively.)

Now there are compact sets $K_1,K_2, \dots \subset U$ such that

$$K_1\subset \text {int}(K_2)\subset K_2 \subset \text {int}(K_3) \subset \dots$$

such that $U= \cup K_n.$ Choose $c_1$ such that $c_1/|z-a_1| < 1/2$ on $K_1.$ If $c_1,\dots c_n$ have been chosen, we choose $c_{n+1}$ such that

$$\frac{c_{n+1}}{|z-a_{n+1}|} < \frac{1}{2^{n+1}},\ \ z\in K_{n+1}\cup E_1 \cup \cdots E_n.$$

Then the series $\sum c_n/(z-a_n)$ converges uniformly on each $K_n,$ hence defines a holomorphic function $f$ on $U.$ Let $a\in \partial U, r > 0.$ Then $D(a,r)$ contains some $a_n,$ hence contains the tail-end of $E_n.$ Thus as $z\to a_n$ within $E_n,$ we have

$$|f(z)| \ge \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{c_n}{z-a_k}\right| - \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\to \infty.$$

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The function $\sum_{n\ge 0}z ^{n!}$ can be seen to be un-extendable for an intrinsic reason: there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ of points in the disk such that $|f(a_n)| \to \infty$,  and every open subset of the disk that is not relatively compact contains a point $a_n$ ( so in fact infinitely many).

Try to find such a sequence $(a_n)$.

$\bf{Added}$ If $0 < z < 1$ and $z = r e^{2\pi \frac{k}{N}}$ then for all $n \ge N$ we have $z^{n!} = |z|^{n!}$. If you fix the argument $2 \pi\frac{k}{N}$ but increase the absolute value towards $1$ you see that $|f(z)| \to \infty$. Just choose $N$ points with arguments $0$, $2\pi \frac{1}{N}$, $\ldots $ , $2 \pi \frac{N-1}{N}$. such that say $f(\cdot)$ is in absolute value $> N$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! But I cannot quite follow it. A subset $A$ of the unit disc not being relatively compact means that the closure of $A$ in the unit disc is not compact, so $A$ has a limit point on the unit circle. But if $A$ only has one limit point on the unit circle, why should the value of $f$ be unbounded on $A$?

Comment: @Chuwei Zhang :  $A$ will contain infinitely many points $a_n$

Comment: I still cannot work out what the $a_n$ should be. Could you tell me how to construct them?

Comment: @Chuwei Zhang: I sketched a sequence that may work. I don't have yet a complete argument.

Comment: Thanks for the added information! I have thought about what you suggested but I couldn't get it to work. Using the notation in your solution, as $N$ increases, $r$ needs to get closer and closer to $1$ in order that $|f(re^{2i\pi k/N})|>N$. So I can take a sequence $b_n$ in the disc that approaches the unit circle such that $b_n$ is not in the closure of $\{a_m:m\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then there is a neighborhood of $\{b_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, which is open and not relatively compact (since $|b_n|\rightarrow 1$), and which does not contain any $a_n$.

Comment: @Chuwei Zhang: I get what you are saying. The hint as stated then is not correct.  Maybe there is a better description for an open neighborhood of a point from the boundary of that domain, not only that it has a limit point on the boundary.  The function $f$ does take large values in the neighborhood of every point of the disk. Somehow we have think of the boundary points of the other region. Still thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Another proof of the claim of zhw is the following:

Given an open set $A$ and a set $B\subset A$ without cluster points in $A$, a slight generalization of Weierstrass factorization theorem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Existence_of_entire_function_with_specified_zeroes), or go to Rudin's "Real and Complex analysis" for a proof) ensure the existence of a function $f\in \mathcal{H}(A):\{z\in A|f(z)=0\}=B$.

Thanks to this theorem, we can easily prove the claim:

Choose as $B$ a sequence that accumulates to every element of $\partial A$: the associated $f$ cannot be analytically extended to a larger open set, as the identity principle would imply $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: Doesn't this only account for one boundary point?

Comment: @Chappers Indeed. Edited, thanks.